# How to create dynamically files names by using the entity fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In the following code, I receive an chunck of 1000 Person entities and I want to dynamically generate files based on the count of the entity received and append data to these files, How can I do this?

```
private static final Date now = new Date();

private String[] headerFields {"name","country"}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> test(){
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>
    .name("generatePersonWriter")
    .headerCallBack(fileWriter -> fileleWriter.writer("name,country"))
    .rsourve(new FileSystemResource("output/person_{{country}}_10.csv"))
    .append(true)
    .delimited()
    .names(headerFields)
    .build;
}
```

Example of expected file output name:

"output/person_France_10.csv"